# OnOffSwitch control is broken

Tags: codenameone

it looks like ON-OFF switch control has been broken and not working on both simulator and devices(iOs and Android). I see new control Switch in place of that control.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your skin file is up to date. This works for me:

```
Form hi = new Form("Switch", BoxLayout.y());
for(int iter = 0 ; iter < 10 ; iter++) {
    Switch touchID = new Switch(); 
    touchID.setValue(iter % 2 == 1);
    hi.add(
        BorderLayout.centerEastWest(new Label("" + ((char)('A' + iter))), 
            touchID, null));
}
hi.show();
```

[image]

Comment: There seems like an issue with new update of codenameone.jar. Things are broken. InfiniteContainer is also not working properly. Please advise